# c++ template with multiple packs, deduction by parameters and return value

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm a little bit confused how c++ interprets following code:

```
template<class ... ReturnTypes, class ... ParameterTypes>
std::tuple<ReturnTypes...> Method(const ParameterTypes & ... Parameters)
{
    (...)
};
```

While compiling following code:

```
std::tuple<unsigned int> R = Object.Method<unsigned int, unsigned int>(10);
```

I'm getting:

```
error: conversion from 'std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int>' to non-scalar type 'std::tuple<unsigned int>' requested
  std::tuple<unsigned int> R = Object.Method<unsigned int, unsigned int>(10);
```

Is there any possibility to create a template method (in non template class) having two parameter packs - one for return types (in tuple) and one for argument types?

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly specify the arguments' types ? You can either get away with `Object.Method<unsigned int>(10);` or even write `template <class ... ParameterTypes> std::tuple<ParameterTypes...> Method(const ParameterTypes & ... Parameters);` instead

Comment: To have at least basic control on argument sizes

Comment: Return types are not always the same as parameter types. This method is used to SELECT data from database, return types are for columns, parameter types for parameter binding

Comment: a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help to understand your use case

Comment: @peku33 something [like this?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2922518088069581)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I am curious why you deleted your answer.  Considered it a bad answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use template template parameters to distinguish between the two parameter packs:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class... T> struct typelist { };

template <typename... ReturnTypes,
          template <typename...> class T,
          class ... ParameterTypes>
std::tuple<ReturnTypes...> Method(T<ReturnTypes...>,
                                  const ParameterTypes & ... Parameters)
{
    return std::tuple<ReturnTypes...>();
};

int main()
{
    using ReturnTypes = typelist<int, char>;
    auto t = Method(ReturnTypes{}, 10, "hello", false);

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t), std::tuple<int,char>>{}, "types do not match");
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>live on ideone</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8atWxx)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a dummy class to separate the types and a helper class to get the right `Method`:

```
template<typename...> class type_pack;

template<typename...> class MethodHelper;

template<typename ... ReturnTypes, typename ... ArgTypes>
class MethodHelper<type_pack<ReturnTypes...>, type_pack<ArgTypes...>>{
    public:
        static_assert(
            sizeof...(ReturnTypes) == sizeof...(ArgTypes),
            "number of return types not the same as argument types"
        );

        static auto Method(ArgTypes ... args){
            return std::tuple<ReturnTypes...>(args...);
        }
};

template<typename ReturnPack, typename ArgsPack, typename ... Args>
auto Method(Args &&... args){
    return MethodHelper<ReturnPack, ArgsPack>::Method(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then you can use it almost like you would have originally:

```
auto main() -> int{
    auto t = Method<type_pack<int, int>, type_pack<size_t, size_t>>(5, 6);
}
```

Or use aliases to make everyones life easier:

```
auto main() -> int{
    static constexpr auto &&my_method = Method<type_pack<int, int>, type_pack<float, float>>::Method;

    auto my_tuple = my_method(1.234f, 5.678f);
}
```

Comment: `std::tuple<ReturnTypes>` doesn't expand `ReturnTypes`. you probably meant `std::tuple<ReturnTypes...>`

Comment: and your code [fails with lvalue arguments](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53b3cc06d6ecbc9d)

Comment: @thanks for pointing that out (y). Could you explain why it doesn't work with rvalues? I'm having a hard time understanding why. If I make an overload for `const ArgTypes&...` it works for lvalues (of course), but then every argument is converted into a `const&`.

Comment: Since `ArgTypes` is not a function template parameter, `ArgTypes&&` doesn't serve as a forwarding reference. It is fixed and equal to what you pass in `type_pack`, e.g. `type_pack<float, float>` makes your function to have a fixed signature `Method(float&&, float&&)`, and this doesn't let you bind lvalues

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki of course! Thanks, I'll fix the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't like your chosen syntax, because it isn't very clear which parameters line up with function arguments, and which with return values.

I can see 3 approaches.

First, keep your syntax:

```
template<class...TypeParams, class...Args>
auto Method( Args&&... args )
-> // magic
```

this is tricky, but we could do a bunch of work to extract the first `sizeof...(TypeParams)-sizeof...(Args)` parameters from `TypeParams`, and make that our return type tuple, and cast the remaining `args...` into the tailing set of `TypeParams`.

Lots of work, and you get a crappy syntax out of it.  I'd pass.

---

A second way would be to explicitly pass a pack type:

```
template<class...>class types_t{using type=types_t; constexpr types_t(){}};
template<class...Ts>constexpr types_t<Ts...> types={};
template<class T>class tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
template<class T>using block_deduction=type_t<tag<T>>;

template<class... Return, class... Args>
std::tuple<Return...> Method(
  types_t<Return...> ret_types, types_t<Args...> arg_types,
  block_deduction<Args>... args
)
```

here we call `Method` like this:

```
auto result = Method( types<double>, types<double>, 3 );
```

where we pass the two type bundles as explicit `type_t<?...>` parameters.  We don't deduce any types, as the C++ types of your args may not line up with the SQL types you want to marshal to.

---

A final method would involve a two-pass solution.  Your args are a bundle: treat them like it:

```
template<class...RetTypes, class...Parms>
std::tuple<RetTypes> Method( std::tuple<Params...> args )
```

use:

```
auto result = Method<double>( std::tuple<double>(3) );
```

we bundle the types into a `std::tuple` of parameters.  This is deduced by `Method`, but can be made explicit via a `std::tuple` construction *outside* the `Method`.  The types passed to `Method` are *only* the return types.

[live example](http://ideone.com/LIQHNd).

Comment: Your `using` statement for `types` isn't valid C++. Are you trying to do a C++14 template variable or a type alias?

Answer (score 0):

This solution exploits C++14 features, but gives you the syntax you want:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename...> struct typelist {};
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template <class... Ts, class... Us>
auto Method3(typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us...>, const typename identity<Us>::type&... parameters)
    -> std::tuple<Ts...>
{
    // (...)
    return {};
}

template <class... Ts, class... Params, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t... Js>
auto Method2(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...>, Params&&... parameters)
    -> decltype(auto)
{
    return Method3(typelist<typename std::tuple_element<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type...>{}
                 , typelist<typename std::tuple_element<sizeof...(Is) + Js, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type...>{}
                 , std::forward<Params>(parameters)...);
}

template <class... Ts, class... Params>
auto Method(Params&&... parameters)
    -> decltype(auto)
{
    return Method2<Ts...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - sizeof...(Params)>{}
                        , std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Params)>{}
                        , std::forward<Params>(parameters)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, short, float> R = Method<int, short, float, double, bool>(3.14, true);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2922518088069581)